# Calculating duration of continuous events in Flink

Tags: apache-flink

I have a stream of some device state changes, for example: `case class DeviceState(ts: Long, state: Int)`. The device sends its state only when it's changed. So, for example, it can be like this:

```
ts | state
----------
 0 | ONLINE
 3 | OFFLINE
11 | ONLINE
19 | OFFLINE
```

(in real code `ts` is unix time milliseconds, I simplified it for example purpose)
I want to partition this stream by tumbling window of 10 ticks and calculate the total duration of each state, so for example if the punctuation was emitted at tick 45, the result should be like this:

```
 window | state   | duration
-----------------------------
 0 - 10 | ONLINE  | 3
 0 - 10 | OFFLINE | 7
10 - 20 | OFFLINE | 2
10 - 20 | ONLINE  | 8
20 - 30 | OFFLINE | 10
30 - 40 | OFFLINE | 10
```

Is it possible to do such duration calculations in Flink? I think it can be made by custom reduce function, but I can't figure out how to emit last state so it will appear in each window (in the example above the last state was at tick 19, but it still should be used in windows 20-30, 30-40 and so on).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Flink's window API, a window doesn't exist until an event is assigned to it, which makes what you are trying to do more difficult.

One solution might be to use a ProcessFunction with a timer to mix into your stream a third type of event that's only used to trigger the windows that would otherwise be empty.

Another solution would be to do all the work of computing the analytics with a ProcessFunction (with some state and timers), rather than windows.